# Partition a graph into connected subgraphs

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, connectedness

I would like to partition a graph into k connected subgraph such that the variance of the number of edges in subgraphs is minimized (i.e. each subgraph should have roughly the same number of edges).  There may be other criteria such as minimizing the variance in the total edge weights of the subgraphs, or achieving some shape related objective such as compactness. Most research I found relates to partitioning with respect to the nodes in the graph, not edges. Any suggestions or references to related literature is greatly appreciated.  Thanks so much!